# how to set dynamic state based on forgot password email

Tags: angularjs, url-routing

I am sending below url to user for forgot-passwor:

http://myapp.client/home/#/reset-password/cykdufapPsD8LJCJBA1EC23C-C1BD-4411-1775-38577DF8FDF3I6U6TfKDXOfN11A1

How to get auth (string after /reset-password/) value and use that in state?

In my app.js file I want to have url of state to be dynamic and redirect user to reset-password page like below:

```
$stateProvider.state('reset-password', {
    url: '/reset-password/:token',
    templateUrl: '/home/login/views/prtl_resetPassword.html'
};
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
```

When I load the page, I am redirected to login page. I can understand that **token** is not assigned which was sent to user eamil. What is the best solution for this?

Comment: TRy it with `http://myapp.client/home/#/reset-password?token=cykdufapPsD8LJCJBA1EC23C-C1BD-4411-1775-38577DF8FDF3I6U6TfKDXOfN11A1`

Comment: @SimonSchüpbach It is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value from the URL fragment `:token` is used to populate [`$stateParams`](https://ui-router.github.io/docs/latest/modules/ng1.html#_stateparams), which can be injected into a controller.

You can create a controller for the `reset-password` state. Inside the controller, you can take the `token` value from `$stateParams` and pass it on to the `login` state with `$state.go()`.

Comment: When I simply added controller to state, it worked fine. Thanks @Tweson Seeoun